# eBay SDK get item in JSON using c#

Tags: c#, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

need item in JSON using c# from ebay sdk

here is python code which does the same thing

```
import pyodbc
import requests, json, re
server=r"DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Trusted_Connection=yes; SERVER=WIN- 
JA0M2L5D05K\ECOM;DATABASE=ebay; UID=sa; PASSWORD=1"
conn = pyodbc.connect(server)
params = (
('callname', 'GetSingleItem'),
('responseencoding', 'JSON'),
('appid', 'abc'),
('siteid', '77'),
('version', '967'),
('ItemID', '111859090492'),
('IncludeSelector', 'Variations,ItemSpecifics,Details,Description,VariationSpecifics'),
)
response = requests.get('http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping';, params=params, verify=False)
x = json.dumps(json.JSONDecoder().decode(response.text))
conn = pyodbc.connect(server)
ccc = conn.cursor()
x=ccc.execute(""" INSERT INTO [ebay].[dbo].[ee] (json) VALUES (?) """,x)
conn.commit()
print(x)
```

I have done this but its throwing excepthin with the result

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // create a new service
        Shopping svc = new Shopping();
        // set the URL and it's parameters
        // Note: appid will go here,
        svc.Url = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?appid=YOUR-ID&version=969&siteid=0&callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=JSON";
        // create a new request type
        GetSingleItemRequestType request = new GetSingleItemRequestType();
        request.ItemID = "111859090492";
        request.IncludeSelector = "Variations,ItemSpecifics,Details,Description,VariationSpecifics";

        // create a new response type
        GetSingleItemResponseType response = new GetSingleItemResponseType();

        try
        {
            // make the call
            response = svc.GetSingleItem(request);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // catch generic exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
            Console.ReadKey();           
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(response);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

the catch block give the result which i nee but it has this error before the actual result

Client found response content type of 'text/plain;charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried, we will not write the code for you.

Comment: JOSEFtw kindly check now

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1121 .

Comment: i have fixed it using HttpWebRequest instead of using the ebay wsdl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked out perfectly for me

```
    private void send(string item)
    {
        string html = "";
        string url = "http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?appid=YOUR-APP-ID&version=969&siteid=77&callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=JSON&IncludeSelector=Variations,ItemSpecifics,Description,Details,VariationSpecifics&ItemID="+item;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        using (HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {


            using (Stream stream = responce.GetResponseStream())
            {

                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {

                    html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }

        }
        textBox1.Text=html;
        html = "";
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        send(txtid.Text);
    }
```